# Unexpected result when trying to calculate Mean and Median

Tags: java, arrays, command-line

I made a simple program that calculate the Mean and Median value of given array from command-line.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class EdankJaya {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double sum = 0;
        double d;
        if(args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage : java EdankJaya <Number1> <Number2> ..");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        //Mean
        for(String s : args) {
            d = Double.parseDouble(s);
            sum = sum+d;
        }
        double mean = sum/args.length;
        System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);
        //Median
        Arrays.sort(args);
        int med = args.length/2;
        if((args.length % 2) == 0) {
            double median1 = Double.parseDouble(args[med-1]);
            double median2 = Double.parseDouble(args[med]);
            System.out.println("Median :"+(median1+median2)/2);
        } else {
            double median = Double.parseDouble(args[med]);
            System.out.println("Median :"+median);
        }
    }
}
```

Technique that i used for Median value is divide `args.length` by 2 and store it in `med`. If `args.length` value is even, it'll be `args[med-1]` + `args[med]`, no problem for even number. And for odd `args.length` value, it'll just be `args[med]`, which is works fine on the paper since integer will not produce fraction(11/2 gonna be 5), but here's what happened:

[image]

Everything's good until i inputted 1-10, the value turned back to the result when i inputted 1-8, and 1-11 just like 1-7, and so on.
What could be the issue here.
Thanks.

Comment: Arrays.sort(args); sorts strings rather than double values so your "2, 3, 4..." will come after "11, 12...". Always, really always, transform the data to the form suitable for the algorithm and only then run alorigthms...

Comment: ah so 11 going to be 1+1, 12 -> 1+2 ?

Comment: No, this is not going to be the case. Strings are sorted by substrings required to make a decision, that is comparing "1" and "2", "1" will come before "2" for obvious reasons, comparing "11" and "2" java will compare the substrings of 1 char first and will see that "1" is before "2", which will be enough; comparing "21" and "2" the comparison of first characters will yield equality, so the next one will be considered and then it is up to Java to decide whether "" comes before "1" or not...

Comment: Alright i see now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array has strings in it, not numbers, so they are not sortting in numerical order.  They're probably sorting in ASCII order.  Since you're already iterating over the array and converting them to numbers, build a second array with them and sort that one.